# SEO - Table with links - better with <a>anchor text</a> or wrap entire row in <a> tag?

Tags: hyperlink, seo, tablerow

I have a table of houses for sale - detailing address, price, size, year of construction, energy rating.

For mobile usability, I've made the entire row as a link - i.e. user can click on nywhere in the row.

Will this impact SEO?

I know the txt on a link can influence context of the destination page - so wondering if it'd be better just to have the `address` part as link, as having the full row as a link results in anchor text of:

`123 Street name, county, state 128m2 $150,000 2007`

where as if linked on address text only:

`123 Street name, county, state`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that these links are internal, from one page on your site to another page which is also on your own site.  If that is the case, the anchor text of the link matters very little. Google only associates the words from anchor text in external links to your site with the linked page to determine what the page is about.

Internally Google finds page titles and headings to be a much better indicator of page content than anchor text, so it uses that much more heavily.